# Como esconder o modal do bootstrap via typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Olhando a documentação do bootstrap eu vi que ele possui um método específico para esconder o modal via jquery:

```
.modal('hide')
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

O problema é que eu uso angular, então preciso de uma forma de realizar a chamada dessa função através do typescript. Usar jquery no meu cenário não é viável e eu preciso remover através do typescript, pois ele só será fechado depois de sucesso de uma requisição http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

Defini uma variável local para o botão de fechar com o data-dismiss da modal:

```
<button [disabled]="loadingVinculacao" #fechaModalVinculacao type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
```

No typescript acessei ele pelo viewchield:

```
  @ViewChild('fechaModalVinculacao') fechaModalVinculacao: ElementRef; //Acesso ao elemento do dom
```

Realizo clique no botão fechar através do typescript se minha requisição for feita com sucesso:

```
this.fechaModalVinculacao.nativeElement.click(); //Fecha o modal se a requisição for feita com sucesso
```